# How do I fix exploding end-to-end constraints when using Cannon.js?

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

### Overview

I'm using **three.js** and **cannon.js** to create jiggly, dangling, cables inside of a 3D world. To create each cable, I have strung together a series of cylinder segments using end-to-end constraints - similar to how you would create a necklace out of dried pasta.

### Problem

As I add more segments to my cables to increase their realism, I seem to hit a threshold where the cable segments start to pull away from each other and shake violently. I believe gravity is pulling apart my end-to-end constraints, forcing the objects that make up my cable to accelerate and spin/bounce/explode out of control. I am able to mitigate this behavior by reducing my world's gravity, but I end up with cables that move and float unnaturally. I'd would like to know how to make a cable out of N segments that doesn't 'pull itself apart'.

[Image on the left shows the cable 'holding together', while the image on the right shows the cable 'exploding' with the addition of more segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAcUF.png)

### Detail

I have a simple method that creates a cable, provided the following parameters:

1. **Length:** The overall length of the cable
2. **Segment Count:** How many segments make up the overall length of the cable
3. **Diameter:** Diameter of each cable segment

My physics world is setup as follows:

1. **Y Gravity:** -30
2. **quatNormalizeSkip:** 0 (using a value greater than 0 makes the chain bounce and explode even worse)
3. **quatNormalizeFast:** false (using true causes explosion)

I developed the following method to create my physics bodies:

```
function addCablesToPhysicsWorld(){
    const cableSegmentMass = 0.001;
    const linearDamping = 0.9;
    const angularDamping = 0.9;

    cables.forEach(cable => {
        const numSegments = cable.segmentPositions.length;
        let previousBody;
        cable.segmentPositions.forEach((segment, index) => {
            const segmentLength = cable.length / numSegments;
            const segmentOverlap = 0.01;
            const physicsBoxLength = (segmentLength / 2) - (segmentOverlap * 2);
            const bodyMass = index === 0 || index === numSegments - 1 ? 0 : cableSegmentMass; // First and last segments of a cable have no mass so they stay in place, all other segments 'sag' between these 'fixed' points
            const currentBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: bodyMass });
            const boxShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(cable.diameter, physicsBoxLength , cable.diameter));
            currentBody.addShape(boxShape);
            currentBody.position.set(segment[0], segment[1], segment[2]);
            currentBody.linearDamping = linearDamping;
            currentBody.angularDamping = angularDamping;
            currentBody.fixedRotation = true;

            if(index === numSegments - 1){
                // If this is the last segment, flip upside down so previous body connects to bottom naturally
                const axis = new CANNON.Vec3(1,0,0);
                const angle = 1.5708 * 2;
                currentBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);
            };
            if(index !== 0){
                // If this is not the first segment, create a single end-to-end constraint with previous body
                const c1 = new CANNON.PointToPointConstraint(
                    currentBody,
                    new CANNON.Vec3(0, physicsBoxLength + segmentOverlap, 0),
                    previousBody,
                    new CANNON.Vec3(0, -physicsBoxLength - segmentOverlap , 0),
                );
                physicsWorld.addConstraint(c1);
            };
            previousBody = currentBody;
            physicsWorld.add(currentBody);
            bodies.push(currentBody);
        });
    });
};
```

Finally, I have experimented with the following settings without much luck:

1. Modifying the mass of each segment
2. Changing the gravity of the world
3. Changing angularDamping and linearDamping
4. Adding padding between the physics bodies
5. Changing solver iterations

I appreciate any assistance!